# Cron job bad day-of-month

Tags: mysql, cron

i'm working on script which will install/setup cron job for mysql backup

This is my script

```
croncmd="5 1 * * * sudo /usr/local/sbin/mysqlFullBackup.sh > /var/log/mysql/mysqlFullBackupCron.log 2>&1"

if [[ $(crontab -l | egrep -v "^(#|$)" | grep -q "$croncmd"; echo $?) == 1 ]]
then
    echo $(crontab -l ; echo "$croncmd") | crontab -
fi
```

The problem is that i'm keep getting error bad day-of-month

```
"-":0: bad day-of-month
errors in crontab file, can't install.
```

Can you please help me properly setup my cron job so it will run every day at 01:10 at night.

If you need any additional informations, please let me know and i will provide.

Thank you

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/610839/how-can-i-programmatically-create-a-new-cron-job

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The script is needlessly complicated. You could do:

```bsh
croncmd='5 1 * * * sudo /usr/local/sbin/mysqlFullBackup.sh > /var/log/mysql/mysqlFullBackupCron.log 2>&1'

if ! crontab -l | egrep -v '^(#|$)' | grep -Fq "$croncmd"
then
    ( crontab -l; echo "$croncmd" ) | crontab -
fi
```

When you do `echo $(crontab -l; echo "$croncmd")`, without any quotes, the contents will be subjected to field-splitting and wildcard expansion when the shell expands it. So any `*` in it will expanded to the filenames in the current directory, for example:

```bsh
$ echo $(echo "*")
bin Desktop dev Documents Downloads examples.desktop Music Pictures Public snap Templates Videos
```

It's easier and simpler to use a compound command - `( crontab -l; echo "$croncmd" )" and send the output to`crontab` directly, without using an additional echo.

---

Also with `grep`, you don't want grep to treat `5 1 *` as a regular expression, so use the `-F` option.

Comment: one problem, script doesn't report any errors now, but is also doesn't add the value in crontab... so current crontab -e is empty

Comment: @DavorBramorPečnik ah, sorry, the `if` condition was to be negated. Forgot that.